# Check if value is in confidence interval

Tags: r

So I have a confidence interval coming back like this

```
        2.5 %        97.5 % 
    -1.1299063   -0.1777965
```

How do I access the values/check if 0 is in the confidence interval programmatically?

I've tried doing

```
interval[1]
```

but that gives me the whole interval.

I've also tried accessing as a data frame, but that doesn't work.

Comment: If both are negative (positive) numbers, then 0 is not in that interval, so check whether all of them are positive (negative). Hint read about `all` function

Comment: yes...I agree - but I'm trying to access this programmatically. Obviously I have a bunch of confidence intervals that I want to check if 0 is in

Comment: Then make your question reproducible and provide a sample of your "bunch of confidence intervals" so that we can give you an answer ;)

Comment: er...wait why? Why does this question require more than what I've put up - I simply want to know how to check if a value is in a confidence interval, or how to access the values of the interval. The CI's are returned to me by confint, how would posting a bunch of examples help?

Comment: Might be object dependent. what is the object you are applying confint to?  I tried with lm objects and have no problems pulling the first value out with interval[1].  Regardless, str(interval) usually helps in order to know what syntax to use

Comment: I think the question of the night here is, how did you arrive at `interval`?

Comment: wait, how is there not a general contract for confidence intervals? This is crazy. Ok...I'm arriving at these via a function that someone else has provided

Comment: R has many different `class`es of objects that, if assumed but not known certainly, can lead to an incorrect result.  I think the fact that it's a double-precision is also important here.  My answer was down-voted, so I deleted it. I apologize for the misinformation.

Comment: Actually I revised it instead. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility (of many):

The product of two numbers can only be negative if one of them is positive and the other negative, i.e., 0 is between them.

```
set.seed(42)
CI <- quantile(rlnorm(10), c(0.025, 0.975))
#       2.5%     97.5% 
#  0.6429574 6.8530659 
prod(CI) < 0
#[1] FALSE

CI <- quantile(rnorm(10), c(0.025, 0.975))
#       2.5%     97.5% 
#  -2.607858  2.069176 
prod(CI) < 0
#[1] TRUE
```

Of course, if you want to be verbose, you can do something like this:

```
unname((CI[1] < 0 && CI[2] > 0) || (CI[1] > 0 && CI[2] < 0))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be entirely too much emphasis being placed on if the interval **should** contain zero, when the real question is if the interval **actually** contains zero. And I read in the SO documentation and meta when I joined that we should try to be as precise as possible with each answer.  So here we go again. Hopefully this revised answer doesn't get down-voted too.

As far as I can tell, you're asking how to extract a specific number from the result of `confint` (check the comments).

From the `confint` documentation file,

---

**Usage**

`confint(object, parm, level = 0.95, ...)`

**Arguments**

`object` - **a fitted model object**

`parm` - a specification of which parameters are to be given confidence intervals, either a vector of numbers or a vector of names. If missing, all parameters are considered.

`level` - the confidence level required.

`...` - additional argument(s) for methods

---

`glm.D93` from `example(confint)` and some added work:

```
> counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
> outcome <- gl(3, 1, 9); treatment <- gl(3, 3)
> glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())

> ci <- confint(glm.D93)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
> ci
                 2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)  2.6958215  3.36655581
outcome2    -0.8577018 -0.06255840
outcome3    -0.6753696  0.08244089
treatment2  -0.3932548  0.39325483
treatment3  -0.3932548  0.39325483

> class(ci)
[1] "matrix"

> ci[1,]
   2.5 %   97.5 % 
2.695822 3.366556 

> ci[1,1]
[1] 2.695822
```

So in reference to your `interval[1]`, use `interval[1,1]`

Comment: not a good idea when the precision in the decimal is not defined. `0 %in% seq(from = -rexp(1), to = rexp(1) , by = 0.000001)` will almost certainly be `FALSE`